# Extrapolate a term in a sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, arithmetic

Maybe it is a very stupid question and I apologized for that, if so.
Consider the **non commutative** product $$\prod_{j=1}^l (a_j+b_j).$$
Is there an explicit form to express it as $$\prod_{j=1}^l (a_j+b_j)=a_1...a_l+something?$$
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sure
$$\sum _{A\subseteq \{1,2,\cdots ,\ell\}}\prod _{i\in A} a_i\prod _{i\not \in A} b_i,$$
not sure how helpful is that tho. Can you clarify what you need?

Comment: Well, the goal is to explicit the prodoct of $a_i$, so it becomes $$\prod_{j=1}^l(a_j+b_j)=\prod_{j=1}^la_j+\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,...,l\},A\neq\{1,...,l\}}\prod_{I\in A}a_i\prod_{I\notin A}b_i.$$
Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that the product is non commutative.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get something even worse. So, in the commutative case we got
$$\sum _{A\subseteq \{1,\cdots ,\ell\}}\prod_{i\in A} a_i\prod_{i\not \in A} b_i,$$
but we are using commutativity of the product, what you can do is first let $a=(a_1,a_2,\cdots ,a_{\ell}),b=(b_1,b_2,\cdots ,b_{\ell})$ and label the variables as a function from $f:[\ell]=\{1,\cdots ,\ell\}\longrightarrow \{a,b\}$ and you will get
$$\sum _{f:[\ell]\longrightarrow \{a,b\}}\prod_{i=1}^{\ell} f(i)_i=a_1\cdots a_{\ell}+\sum _{\substack{f:[\ell]\longrightarrow \{a,b\}\\f^{-1}(b)\neq \emptyset}}\prod_{i=1}^{\ell} f(i)_i.$$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Is the sum over any (injective) function from $\{1,...,l\}$ to $\{a,b\}$?

Comment: Here is how I tried to wrote that, maybe it is not the most elegant way, but I think it works.
$$\prod_{j=1}^m(a_j+b_j)=a_{\{1,...,m\}}+\sum_{A\subsetneq\{1,...,m\}}a_A*b_{A^c},$$
where $a_A:=a_{i_1}\cdot...\cdot a_{i_s}$ if $A=\{i_1,...,i_s\}$ and $b_{A^c}=b_{j_1}\cdot...\cdot b_{j_{m-s}}$ if $A^c=\{j_1,...,j_{m-s}\}$ and 
$$a_i*b_j=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
&a_i\cdot b_j\qquad if \ i<j\\
&b_j\cdot a_i\qquad if \ i>j.
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: @GiulioBinosi Yeah, the $j$'s are what the function encodes.

Comment: But if I sum on every function which admits at least one $b$,I have too many terms, like if $m=3$, I should have $2^3$ terms, while the functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ which have at least one value in $b=\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ are $6^3-3^3$. Probably I don't understand your notation

Comment: @GiulioBinosi No, the image is just $a$ or $b$ and then you take the index in the product. So there are also $2^3$ terms.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean and probably I prefer your way to mine. Thank you very much!

Comment: @GiulioBinosi You are welcome!